# Azure function precompiled timerTrigger error

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-webjobssdk

I deploy an Azure Function precompiled with a timerTrigger. I have the following exception when I activate all logs

> 2017-04-13T12:53:03.836
>   {"id":"b91045c2-ff21-4c9d-bd14-88e90723adbe","requestId":"37212a13-73ae-4e1e-9f1e-130f3865e258","statusCode":500,"errorCode":0,"messsage":"Sequence
>   contains no matching element"} 2017-04-13T12:53:03.836
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching
>   element    at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1
>   source, Func`2 predicate)    at
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Controllers.AdminController.Invoke(String
>   name, FunctionInvocation invocation)    at lambda_method(Closure ,
>   Object , Object[] )    at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.b__9(Object
>   instance, Object[] methodParameters)    at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object
>   instance, Object[] arguments)    at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

My function.json

```
{
  "scriptFile": "..\\bin\\Plop.Statistics.dll",
  "entryPoint": "Plop.Statistics.S4BStatisticsCommand.Function.Run",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myTimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 */1 * * * *"
    },
    {
      "name": "outputQueueItem",
      "queueName": "command-queue",
      "type": "queue",
      "direction": "out",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

and my function

```
namespace Plop.Statistics.S4BStatisticsCommand{
public class Function
{
    public static async Task Run(TimerInfo myTimer, ICollector<S4BStatisticCommand> outputQueueItem, TraceWriter log)
    {
       log.Info("hello");
    }
```

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT:**

The timerTrigger is not triggered because the function is not found. Here the logs:

> 2017-04-14T08:54:11.773 File change of type 'Created' detected
>   for:\home\site\wwwroot\S4BStatisticsCommand'
>
> 2017-04-14T08:54:11.773 Host configuration has changed. Signaling
>   restart
>
> 2017-04-14T08:54:12.167 File change of type 'Created' detected for
>   'D:\home\site\wwwroot\S4BStatisticsCommand\function.json'
>
> 2017-04-14T08:54:12.167 Host configuration has changed. Signaling
>   restart
>
> 2017-04-14T08:54:12.281 File change of type 'Changed' detected for
>   'D:\home\site\wwwroot\S4BStatisticsCommand\function.json'
>
> 2017-04-14T08:54:12.281 Host configuration has changed. Signaling
>   restart
>
> 2017-04-14T08:54:12.785 Stopping Host
>
> 2017-04-14T08:54:12.832 Job host stopped
>
> 2017-04-14T08:54:12.894 Host instance
>   'f3bf62b4fcd9d52410e4b055937d68db' released lock lease.
>
> 2017-04-14T08:54:12.957 Reading host configuration file
>   'D:\home\site\wwwroot\host.json'
>
> 2017-04-14T08:54:13.317 Host lock lease acquired by instance ID
>   'f3bf62b4fcd9d52410e4b055937d68db'.
>
> 2017-04-14T08:54:14.070 Generating 1 job function(s)
>
> 2017-04-14T08:54:14.097 Starting Host
>   (HostId=4ab0f60d5dc84308a2fd847b978c468b, Version=1.0.10841.0,
>   ProcessId=8628, Debug=True, Attempt=0)
>
> 2017-04-14T08:54:14.113 Development settings applied
>
> 2017-04-14T08:54:14.113 No job functions found. Try making your job
>   classes and methods public. If you're using binding extensions (e.g.
>   ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration
>   method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g.
>   config.UseServiceBus(), config.UseTimers(), etc.).
>
> 2017-04-14T08:54:14.113 Job host started

Comment: Your run function is truncated

Comment: nothing special in it

Comment: is the Cron definition valid? http://cron.schlitt.info

Comment: Yes ! I tried many different. But the expcetion is in Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Controllers.AdminController.Invoke

Comment: What versions of `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs` nugets are you using in your precompiled function?

Also, this particular error appears to occur when you run manually from the portal - do you also see the error if the timer trigger runs organically?

Comment: Yes, I have this error when I run manually. The WebJob SDK is "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs" versio 2.0.0 targetting net461. I don't see any logs when the timer trigger should run...

Comment: The timerTrigger is not triggered becaus the function is not found. Here the log

Answer (score 1):

Timer Triggers require the [Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions/) nuget, the job host should register your function.

See this [precompiled function article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/03/16/publishing-a-net-class-library-as-a-function-app/), specifically the 'converting to class files' section.

> 3. If you’re using timer triggers, add the NuGet package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.

Answer (score 1):

I have a timer trigger working on a precompiled function using a slightly different definition of the Run function.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;

namespace PrecompiledDLL
{
    public partial class PrecompiledFunction
    {
        public static async Task Run(TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info("Hello World");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what i was exactly looking for. Thanks for the code. No proper sample in the internet...